# How can i implement MVC architecture with Jquery mobile

Tags: android, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am developing jquery mobile application with php serverside. I want to know is there any way to split views ,controllers and models in jquery mobile.
Beacause writing views and controllers in one file is messing up with files.
How can i implement MVC architecture in [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all my search i found backbone js will solve my problem i think. [backbone.js](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials)[2](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jquerymobile)

backbone javascript is providing view, models and collections to achieve MVC architecture with jquery mobile. But yet to search is this how much it is compatible with google maps like driving views and that map  directions.

Please discuss your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any jQuery mobile code in your controllers or models.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'I want to know is there any way to split views controllers and models in jquery mobile' -- this is all PHP, jQuery mobile should only exist in your views.

Just create a regular ol' MVC setup and use jQuery mobile stuff in the views.

I used jQuery mobile on a rails site and just created a .mobile and a .tablet view for each page. jQuery mobile only effects the look, its purely a views thing.

edit: There was some more rails work to trigger 'mobile or not' but since you're in php thats not worth delving into.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). It is not MVC but MVVC framework, however it will provide you with separation of presentation from logic you are looking for. Here is [example](http://operationmobile.com/quick-tip-for-using-knockout-js-and-jquery-mobile-list-dividers/) and [jsFiddle prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/ycQwH/3/) of using it with JQM.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to integrate it with [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org). I have used it a bit and it's easy and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't combine model, views and controllers all into you javascript layer (unless you are using something like Knockout.js in which case you don't even need PHP)

If you are using server side programming, then Javascript it simply an enhancer for your views.

Just use any PHP MVC framework and display different views depending on the browser (mobile or desktop). Then use jquery mobile to render a mobile friendly version.